# Capitalization of "the" in "the Bible"

Tags: orthography, capitalization, definite-articles, proper-nouns

Which of these is correct capitalization?

> - Mrs. Ohana gave me the Bible.
> - Mrs. Ohana gave me The Bible.

Comment: And one thing I want to ask.help me plz how to register my email on stack exchange?? Why I can't vote or answer any question?

Comment: Please read about reputation.

Comment: You should accept deadrat's answer. Click on the tick to make it change into green.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't have any knowledge about this.now I have done this.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of style.  *The Chicago Manual of Style* does not capitalize the article, and a brief look with the google doesn't find anyone who disagrees with that choice.  Don't capitalize the word "the" before "Bible" unless "the" is the first word in a sentence.

Comment: What about *The Holy Bible*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA As opposed to ... what?  (The *CMS* capitalizes all words in the names -- King James, Authorized, Holy -- but doesn't include the article.)

Comment: +1 You're right, I guess I'm so used to hearing *the* in front of *Holy Bible* I thought it was part of its title.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I thought you might have had a not-so-Holy version in mind.  Imagine my disappointment.

Comment: I'd capitalize Google though :)

Comment: And not use a preceding article.  The google and I are on lower-case name basis.